# MySQL UPDATE statement works in query but not in PHP code

Tags: php, mysql

When I execute the statement in phpmyadmin, it works properly, but when I copy and paste the exact same query into this php file, it doesn't work.

**PHP Code:**

```
if($_GET['vote'] == 1) {
    echo "if statement ran";
    $sql = "UPDATE raids SET attendees = attendees +1 WHERE dateposted =  '2017-08-19 16:15:46'";
    mysql_query($sql, $link);
}
```

My link variable does work and the 'if' statement executes. Other SQL statements haven't given me trouble.

Why isn't the php code incrementing 'attendees' when used in the PHP code?

Comment: [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) tells you why. If it doesn't then it means the `WHERE` clause didn't match any row.

Comment: Try adding `mysql_query($sql, $link) or die(mysql_error());` to see more information. Side note: mysql_* is deprecated. You should use mysqli or PDO along with prepared statements.

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** _mysql_*-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. You are **wide open to** [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Milan Chheda said, MySQL is deprecated and is no longer secure. Use PDO or at least MySQLi instead.

**MySQLi implementation for your code:**

```
    //MySQLi information

    $db_host     = "localhost";
    $db_username = "username";
    $db_password = "password";

    //connect to mysqli database (Host/Username/Password)
    $connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die("Error " . mysqli_error());

    //select MySQLi dabatase table
    $db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "table") or die("Error " . mysqli_error());

    if(isset($_GET['vote']) && $_GET['vote'] !== NULL) {

$vote = $_GET['vote'];

if($vote == "1") {
    echo "Vote is 1, updating the database";
    $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE raids SET attendees = attendees + '1' WHERE dateposted =  '2017-08-19 16:15:46'");
}

}
```

I hope this helped you. Good luck!